# Firebase realtime database hiscore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get user's data (like nickname,country) who is champion.
In my example I want to get data of nickname3 because who has 863 hiScore.It means nickname3 is champion.

I tried some thing but it is not working. In my opinion firstly I should find  the champion's reference. After finding reference of champion, I can try get values of children of champion.

Can you help me. How can I get the values of the champion.

[image]

What I tried is

```
override fun getHiScoreInFirebase(interfaceCallback: InterfaceCallback) {

    var ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("user").orderByChild("HiScore").limitToLast(1).ref
    ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
           if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

            val hiScore=   dataSnapshot.child("HiScore").getValue() as Int
            val kullaniciAdi=   dataSnapshot.child("KullaniciAdi").getValue() as String
            val sehir=  dataSnapshot.child("Sehir").getValue() as String
            val ulke= dataSnapshot.child("Ulke").getValue() as String

            interfaceCallback.hiScoreSonucCallback(hiScore,kullaniciAdi,ulke,sehir)

        }}

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

        }


    })}
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried something from the firebase API?

Comment: Yess I editted the question. Thanks Zain for your interest.

Comment: Tank you Mr Puffelen. What about How can I fınd the reference of champion who has the biggest hiScore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

So in your case you need to handle the fact that the `dataSnapshot` contains a list of child nodes by looping over `dataSnapshot.children`. Something like this:

```
override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
  for (userSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
    val hiScore= userSnapshot.child("HiScore").getValue() as Int
    val kullaniciAdi= userSnapshot.child("KullaniciAdi").getValue() as String
    val sehir= userSnapshot.child("Sehir").getValue() as String
    val ulke= userSnapshot.child("Ulke").getValue() as String

    interfaceCallback.hiScoreSonucCallback(hiScore,kullaniciAdi,ulke,sehir)
  }
}
```

---

**Update**: You're also calling `.ref` at the end of a query, which means you're throwing all conditions from that query away.

This:

```
var ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("user").orderByChild("HiScore").limitToLast(1).ref
```

Is just a very long way of saying:

```
var ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("user")
```

To actually keep and use the query, do:

```
var query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("user").orderByChild("HiScore").limitToLast(1)
query.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
```

Comment: Tank you Mr Puffelen. What about How can I fınd the reference of champion who has the biggest hiScore.

Comment: You mean `userSnapshot.getKey()`/`userSnapshot.getRef()`?

Comment: I mean I want to get children data of champion. I think it is about value of HiScore. I wrote " var ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("user").orderByChild("HiScore").limitToLast(1).ref" but it is giving wrong users data. How can I find the true user.

Comment: That `.ref` at the end is wrong. I updated my answer.

Comment: Tank you Mr Puffelen. You are great. Thank you again.